# That X and Y “has” or “have” done Z?

Tags: grammar, verb-agreement, compound-subjects, singular-subject-and-verb

I came across this sentence in a book.

> That unique scale and perspective has informed all of his thinking on the care and feeding of software systems.

With the “that” at the beginning of the sentence, I can’t determine if the subject is singular or plural. Whether “has” or “have” is appropriate depends on the number of the subject. Which is correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"That unique scale and perspective" is plural, given the presence of the *and.* The word "that" has to agree with both *scale* and *perspective,* which are singular nouns, which is why we use "that" instead of "those," but the whole noun phrase is still plural (Huddleston & Pullum (2002), p. 1334).

But that doesn't necessarily mean that the singular verb  form *has* is incorrect. If the "scale and perspective" is conceptualized as a single combined source of his information, then a singular verb can be used there; this use of a singular verb form with a plural subject is largely limited to cases where the subject denotes a combination of abstract entities, as in sentences like "Your laziness and ineptitude amazes me" (Huddleston & Pullum (2002), pp. 507-508).